# ANTLR ParserInterpreter

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to create an [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org) ParserInterpreter following [this guide](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/interpreters.md#java-target-interpreter-setup). From the third example on that page, labeled *To load separate lexer/parser grammars,…*, I see the following code:

```
public static ParseTree parse(String fileNameToParse,
                          String lexerGrammarFileName,
                          String parserGrammarFileName,
                          String startRule)
throws IOException{

    final LexerGrammar lg = (LexerGrammar) Grammar.load(lexerGrammarFileName);

    final Grammar pg = Grammar.load(parserGrammarFileName, lg);

    CharStream input = CharStreams.fromPath(Paths.get(fileNameToParse));
    LexerInterpreter lexEngine = lg.createLexerInterpreter(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexEngine);
    ParserInterpreter parser = pg.createParserInterpreter(tokens);
    ParseTree t = parser.parse(pg.getRule(startRule).index);
    System.out.println("parse tree: " + t.toStringTree(parser));
    return t;
}
```

On line 5 `Grammar.load` is passed two parameters, a `String` and a `LexerGrammar`. However, the JavaDoc for [`org.antlr.v4.tool.Grammar`](https://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/org/antlr/v4/tool/Grammar.html) shows the [`load`](https://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/org/antlr/v4/tool/Grammar.html#load(java.lang.String)) method taking only one parameter.

Am I missing something here? If not, is there a workaround to create a ParserInterpreter given a lexer grammar and a parser grammar file?